# How to construct a method chain from an array of method names

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, substring

Let me show you an example of what I want to accomplish:

Say I want to call a functions sub function's sub function's sub function (and so on, lets say for 50+ sub functions), like:

```
foo(arg).bar(other).foobar(int, str).execute(str)
```

and imagine that there are 50+ sub functions, so it would be pretty impractical to type out each sub-call.

SO: **How do I write a function to call the sub-function of the sub-function etc... (based on the array length)?**, based on an array like this (for example):

```
[["foo",["asdf"]],["bar",["other"]],["foobar",[123,"hi"]],["execute",["today"]]]
```

To be clear, I'm NOT simply trying to call a each function in the array individually with the corresponding parameters, I could do that easily with:

```
arr.forEach(x=>functionDictionary(x[0])(...x[1])
```

I want to simply get this:

```
foo(arg).bar(other).foobar(int, str).execute(str)
```

from this:

```
[["foo",["asdf"]],["bar",["other"]],["foobar",[123,"hi"]],["execute",["today"]]]
```

Comment: _"Call a method on the return value of another method"_ would be better wording. _"Construct a method chain from an array of method names"_ would be even better.

Comment: @Eric Good idea :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduce` to iterate over the array and call each function, and pass along the return value to the next iteration as the accumulator:

```js
// using just a single object to make the indentation much more readable:
const obj = {
  foo(arg) {
    console.log('foo called with ' + arg);
    return this;
  },
  bar(arg2) {
    console.log('bar called with ' + arg2);
    return this;
  },
  foobar(argA, argB) {
    console.log('foobar called with ' + argA + ' ' + argB);
    return this;
  },
  execute(arg5) {
    console.log('execute called with ' + arg5);
    return this;
  }
};

const arr = [
  ["foo", ["asdf"]],
  ["bar", ["other"]],
  ["foobar", [123, "hi"]],
  ["execute", ["today"]]
];
arr.reduce((a, [key, args]) => a[key](...args), obj);
```

Note that here I'm passing in `obj` as the initial value, so that the first `["foo"]` can access `obj.foo`, rather than using `eval` to reference a variable in the current scope named `foo`.

Comment: Wow that's really cool, I never even knew about the reduce method! And also I didn't know you can declare functions like that in an object literal... Would it be possible to do the same if each of the functions didn't return a value?

Comment: If the functions didn't return anything, then your desired output call format of `foo(arg).bar(other).foobar(int, str).execute(str)` doesn't make sense. If all the functions were in an object or something though, like in my answer, then you could simply access the appropriate property of the object on each iteration.

Comment: I admit you are right, I was mistaken, however the other answer doesn't need to use reduce (nothing against reduce it's just an extra step)

Comment: I chose `reduce` because it's completely self-contained - there's no need for an extra outside variable. The other answer's outside variable is much more of an extra step

Comment: I guess but what if one of the objects happens to not return a variable / not be callable, is there a way to check for that?

Comment: Since you want to imitate your desired `foo(arg).bar(other).foobar(int, str).execute(str)`, then it will result in an error, just like that code does. If you want the chain to fail silently then you can use the same sort of conditional operator logic, `=> a ? a[key](...args) : 0`

Comment: OK I concede again

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
arr.forEach( x => r=r[x[0]](...x[1]) );
```

where arr contains your array with function names-arguments, r contains object with function (and result at the end).

```js
const o = {
  fun1(arg) { console.log('fun1 ' + arg); return this;},
  fun2(arg1,arg2) { console.log('fun2 ' + arg1 +'-'+ arg2); return this; },
  fun3(arg) { console.log('fun3 ' + arg); return this;},  
};

const arr = [
  ["fun1", ["abc"]],  
  ["fun2", [123, "def"]],
  ["fun3", ["ghi"]]
];


let r=o; // result
arr.forEach( x => r=r[x[0]](...x[1]) );
```

In case if you want to break call chain when function not return next object then use this

```
arr.forEach( x => r= r ? r[x[0]](...x[1]) : 0 );
```

```js
const o = {
  fun1(arg) { console.log('fun1 ' + arg); return this;},
  fun2(arg1,arg2) { console.log('fun2 ' + arg1 +'-'+ arg2); },
  fun3(arg) { console.log('fun3 ' + arg); return this;},  
};

const arr = [
  ["fun1", ["abc"]],  
  ["fun2", [123, "def"]],
  ["fun3", ["ghi"]]
];


let r=o; // result
arr.forEach( x => r= r ? r[x[0]](...x[1]) : 0 );
```